# resampling non-time-series data

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data which I'm handling with dataframes and pandas.
They contain about 10 000 rows and 6 columns.

The problem is, that I have done several trials and the different datasets have slightly different index numbers.
(It's a "force - length" testing with several materials and of course the measurement points are not alined perfectly.)

Now my idea was, to "resample" the data using the index which contains the value for the length.
It seems that the resampling function in pandas is only available for datetime datatypes.

I tried to convert the index via to_datetime and succeeded. But after the resampling, I need to get back to the original scale. some kind of from_datetime function.

Is there any way or am I on the completely wrong track and should better use functions like groupby?

**Edit to add:**

Data looks like below. Length is used as index. Of those Dataframes I have a few so that it would be really nice to align them all to the same "framerate" and then cut them e.g. so that I can compare different datasets.

The Idea I already tried was this one:

```
df_1_dt = df_1  # generate a table for the conversion
# convert it simulating seconds.. good idea?!
df_1_dt.index = pd.to_datetime(df_1_dt.index, unit='s')
df_1_dt_rs = df_1_dt  # generate a df for the resampling
df_1_dt_rs = df_1_dt_rs.resample(rule='s')  # resample by the generated time
```

Data:

```
¦  Index (Length)   ¦    Force1     ¦    Force2     ¦  
¦-------------------+---------------+---------------¦  
¦ 8.04662074828e-06 ¦ 4.74251270294 ¦ 4.72051584721 ¦  
¦ 8.0898882798e-06  ¦ 4.72051584721 ¦ 4.72161570191 ¦  
¦ 1.61797765596e-05 ¦ 4.69851899147 ¦ 4.72271555662 ¦  
¦ 1.65476570973e-05 ¦ 4.65452528    ¦ 4.72491526604 ¦  
¦ 2.41398605024e-05 ¦ 4.67945501539 ¦ 4.72589291467 ¦  
¦ 2.42696630876e-05 ¦ 4.70438475079 ¦ 4.7268705633  ¦  
¦ 9.60953101751e-05 ¦ 4.72931448619 ¦ 4.72784821192 ¦  
¦ 0.00507703541206  ¦ 4.80410369237 ¦ 4.73078115781 ¦  
¦ 0.00513927175509  ¦ 4.87889289856 ¦ 4.7337141037  ¦  
¦ 0.00868965311878  ¦ 4.9349848032  ¦ 4.74251282215 ¦  
¦ 0.00902026197556  ¦ 4.99107670784 ¦ 4.7513115406  ¦  
¦ 0.00929150878827  ¦ 5.10326051712 ¦ 4.76890897751 ¦  
¦ 0.0291729332784   ¦ 5.14945375919 ¦ 4.78650641441 ¦  
¦ 0.0296332588857   ¦ 5.17255038023 ¦ 4.79530513287 ¦  
¦ 0.0297080942518   ¦ 5.19564700127 ¦ 4.80410385132 ¦  
¦ 0.0362595526707   ¦ 5.2187436223  ¦ 4.80850321054 ¦  
¦ 0.0370305483177   ¦ 5.24184024334 ¦ 4.81290256977 ¦  
¦ 0.0381506204153   ¦ 5.28803348541 ¦ 4.82170128822 ¦  
¦ 0.0444440795306   ¦ 5.30783069134 ¦ 4.83050000668 ¦  
¦ 0.0450121369102   ¦ 5.3177292943  ¦ 4.8348993659  ¦  
¦ 0.0453465140473   ¦ 5.32762789726 ¦ 4.83929872513 ¦  
¦ 0.0515533437013   ¦ 5.33752650023 ¦ 4.85359662771 ¦  
¦ 0.05262489708     ¦ 5.34742510319 ¦ 4.8678945303  ¦  
¦ 0.0541273847206   ¦ 5.36722230911 ¦ 4.89649033546 ¦  
¦ 0.0600755845953   ¦ 5.37822067738 ¦ 4.92508614063 ¦  
¦ 0.0607712385295   ¦ 5.38371986151 ¦ 4.93938404322 ¦  
¦ 0.0612954159368   ¦ 5.38921904564 ¦ 4.9536819458  ¦  
¦ 0.0670288249293   ¦ 5.39471822977 ¦ 4.97457891703 ¦  
¦ 0.0683640870058   ¦ 5.4002174139  ¦ 4.99547588825 ¦  
¦ 0.0703192637772   ¦ 5.41121578217 ¦ 5.0372698307  ¦  
¦ 0.0757871634772   ¦ 5.43981158733 ¦ 5.07906377316 ¦  
¦ 0.0766597757545   ¦ 5.45410948992 ¦ 5.09996074438 ¦  
¦ 0.077317850103    ¦ 5.4684073925  ¦ 5.12085771561 ¦  
¦ 0.0825991083545   ¦ 5.48270529509 ¦ 5.13295596838 ¦  
¦ 0.0841354654428   ¦ 5.49700319767 ¦ 5.14505422115 ¦  
¦ 0.0865525182528   ¦ 5.52559900284 ¦ 5.1692507267  ¦
```

Comment: Please post a small example of your data and the desired output.

Comment: There should be some other ways to do this, but they depend on how you want to resample it.  What is the purpose of resampling here?  Do you want to interpolate missing values?  Have values at more regular intervals?  Maybe you could describe you desired output as well.

Answer (score 4):

I found how to do this by using reindex and interpolate.

This is the result: Blue points are the original data and red line-points the reindexed/interpolated data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKlxW.png)

And here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'X' : [1.1, 2.05, 3.07, 4.2],
                   'Y1': [10.1, 15.2, 35.3, 40.4],
                   'Y2': [55.05, 40.4, 84.17, 31.5]})
print(df)

df.set_index('X',inplace =True)
print(df)

Xresampled = np.linspace(1,4,15)
print(Xresampled)

#Resampling
#df = df.reindex(df.index.union(resampling))

#Interpolation technique to use. One of:

#'linear': Ignore the index and treat the values as equally spaced. This is the only method supported on MultiIndexes.
#'time': Works on daily and higher resolution data to interpolate given length of interval.
#'index', 'values': use the actual numerical values of the index.
#'pad': Fill in NaNs using existing values.
#'nearest', 'zero', 'slinear', 'quadratic', 'cubic', 'spline', 'barycentric', 'polynomial': Passed to scipy.interpolate.interp1d. These methods use the numerical values of the index. Both 'polynomial' and 'spline' require that you also specify an order (int), e.g. df.interpolate(method='polynomial', order=5).
#'krogh', 'piecewise_polynomial', 'spline', 'pchip', 'akima': Wrappers around the SciPy interpolation methods of similar names. See Notes.
#'from_derivatives': Refers to scipy.interpolate.BPoly.from_derivatives which replaces 'piecewise_polynomial' interpolation method in scipy 0.18.

df_resampled = df.reindex(df.index.union(Xresampled)).interpolate('values').loc[Xresampled]
print(df_resampled)

# gca stands for 'get current axis'
ax = plt.gca()
df.plot(           style='X',  y='Y2', color = 'blue', ax=ax, label = 'Original Data'     )
df_resampled.plot( style='.-', y='Y2', color = 'red',  ax=ax, label = 'Interpolated Data' )
ax.set_ylabel('Y1')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like all you want to do is round the length figures to a lower precision.

If this is the case, you could just use the in-built rounding function:

(dummy data)

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame([[1.0000005,4],[1.232463632,5],[5.234652,9],[5.675322,10]],columns=['length','force'])
>>> df
33:      length  force
0  1.000001      4
1  1.232464      5
2  5.234652      9
3  5.675322     10
>>> df['rounded_length'] = df.length.apply(round, ndigits=0)
>>> df
34:      length  force  rounded_length
0  1.000001      4             1.0
1  1.232464      5             1.0
2  5.234652      9             5.0
3  5.675322     10             6.0
>>>
```

Then you could replicate the resample().... workflow using groupby:

```
>>> df.groupby('rounded_length').mean().force
35: rounded_length
1.0     4.5
5.0     9.0
6.0    10.0
Name: force, dtype: float64
```

Generally, resample IS just for dates. If you're using it for something other than dates, there's probably a more elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem to you, and I found a solution. The solution is essentially

Integreate -> Interpolate -> Differentiate

First I will describe the problem I am solving to make sure we are on the same page. A simple example is if you have points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), and you want (x0', y0'), (x1', y1') (you know x0', x1' and wany to find y1'), with x0' < x1 < x1' < x2, then you want to take a weighted average, so y1' = ((x1' - x1) * y2 + (x1 - x0') * y1) / (x1' - x0').

The way to do this is integrate, then interpolate, then differentiate. Say you have a data frame with columns `'x'` and `'y'`, but you want to resample to a new x `new_x`, which a numpy.ndarray.

```
df['integral'] = (df['y'] * (df['x'] - df['x'].shift(1))).cumsum()
new_integral = np.interp(new_x, df['x'].values, df['integral'].values, left=0., right=np.nan)
new = pd.DataFrame({'new_x': new_x, 'integral': new_integral})
new['y'] = (new['integral'] - new['integral'].shift(1)) / (new['new_x'] - new['new_x'].shift(1))
```

I would start `new_x` with `0.` and then drop the first value from the new data frame, because it will be `NaN`. You can also fill and trailing `NaN` at high x with whatever you want.

I hope this solves your problem. I haven't included a proof that this method sovles the problem defined above, but it is not hard to show.