# pandas dataframe resample column of non-timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have two sets of data (dataframes), each with two columns which relate to eachother (lets call them x and y), like such:

set 1:

```
x   |   y
0.1 |   1
0.2 |   2
0.3 |   3
0.4 |   2
0.5 |   3
0.6 |   4
0.7 |   5
```

set 2:

```
x    |   y
0.12 |   0
0.21 |   2
0.31 |   5
0.44 |   4
0.52 |   3
0.61 |   1
0.76 |   1
```

I want to sum the y values of both sets (at equal x points), however x is slightly misaligned. To solve this I thought it would be best to interpolate both sets from x = 0.12 to 0.7 in 0.001 steps, essentially:

```
mini = max(set1.x.min(), set2.x.min())
maxi = max(set1.x.max(), set2.x.max())
x_interpolation_points = np.arange(maxi, mini, 0.001)

# Next step: interpolate both sets
# last step: sumY = set1.y + set2.y
```

How would one accomplisch this? In case of a timeserie I would use resample().interpolate(), but this is not a timeserie..

Comment: You can `interpolate` on a normal series see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html#pandas.Series.interpolate)

Comment: Thats what I thought, but in the docs I don't see any options on how to interpolate to specific values.

Comment: Why not just do `set2['x'] = set2['x'].round(1)` so the values match? Or do you want to interpoalte Set1 so it matches Set2 exactly? You could therefore do `set1.set_index('x').reindex(np.arange(maxi, mini, 0.001)
)` and then you can `merge this

Comment: If I do this:
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0.12, 0.19, 0.28, 0.41], 'y': [1,2,2,5]})
df.set_index('x').reindex(np.arange(0.12, 0.41, 0.01))

It only has the first value for Y, the other ones are missing..

Comment: I think the issue here is the imprecision of float values in the index, this isn't so straightforward now thinking about it

Comment: See my anser to this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560198/resampling-non-time-series-data/57110084#57110084

Answer (score 1):

In the end I solved it using numpy: numpy.interp()