# Pandas bin dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a depth column with a 0.1 m grid.

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'depth': [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1 ],
            '350': [7.898167, 6.912074, 6.049002, 5.000357, 4.072320, 3.070662, 2.560458, 2.218879, 1.892131, 1.588389, 1.573693],
            '351': [8.094912, 7.090584, 6.221289, 5.154516, 4.211746, 3.217615, 2.670147, 2.305846, 1.952723, 1.641423, 1.622722],
            '352': [8.291657, 7.269095, 6.393576, 5.308674, 4.351173, 3.364569, 2.779837, 2.392813, 2.013316, 1.694456, 1.671752],
            '353': [8.421007, 7.374317, 6.496641, 5.403691, 4.439815, 3.412494, 2.840625, 2.443868, 2.069017, 1.748445, 1.718081 ],
            '354': [8.535562, 7.463452, 6.584512, 5.485725, 4.517310, 3.438680, 2.890678, 2.487039, 2.123644, 1.802643, 1.763818 ],
            '355': [8.650118, 7.552586, 6.672383, 4.517310, 4.594806, 3.464867, 2.940732, 2.530211, 2.178271, 1.856841, 1.809555 ]},
            index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
             )
```

My question is: how do I bin the data to get a new dataframe on a 0.5 m depth frequency?

Or rather, how do I average the column values from df1 (which have data per each 0.1 m) for the dz=0.5 m bins?

The point is to get the same df structure, same columns (350-355), but the rows should be averaged/binned per column for a certain dz interval (number of rows), let's say 0.5 m

So my new dataframe would have only two rows in this case with depth values of 1.35 and 1.85 m, keeping each column as in df1. 
The first one would have averaged values for the 1.1-1.6m interval, the second one from 1.6-2.1 m .

Comment: Please explain more

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, thanks for pointing it out. I hope it's clearer now

Comment: I am sorry, but I personally still didnt get you

Comment: something like this would probably work:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560198/resampling-non-time-series-data

Comment: @JohnE : no, not really. The point is to get the same df structure, same columns (350-355), but the rows should be averaged/binned per column for a certain dz interval (number of rows), let's say 0.5 m.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, can't get clearer than this, please check the latest edit if you're interested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a combination of `df.groupby`and `pd.cut`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Specifiy your desired dz step size
step = 0.5
dz = np.arange(1,3,step)

# rebin dataframe
df2 = df1.groupby(pd.cut(df1.depth, dz, labels=False), as_index=False).mean()

# refill 'depth' column
df2.depth = dz[:-1]
```

gives

```
depth   350     351     352     353     354     355
0   1.0     5.986384    6.154609    6.322835    6.427094    6.517312    6.397441
1   1.5     2.266104    2.357551    2.448998    2.502890    2.548537    2.594184
2   2.0     1.573693    1.622722    1.671752    1.718081    1.763818    1.809555
```

where in each line there is the mean of the `35x` columns within `1 < x <= 1.5`, `1.5 < x <= 2`, etc...

You can easily change the rebinning by selecting a desired value for the `step` variable.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you so much! Just one more question: could one link dz to the df1 depth column somehow? Let's say I do know the step, but the depth ranges are changing from one to another dataframe?

Comment: @PEBKAC: wouldn't that just be `dz = np.arange(df1.depth.min(), df1.depth.max(), step)`?

Comment: @DarenThomas, yes, you're absolutely right. It could be the most elegant solution! Thank you all so much!

Comment: @JohnE, would you mind writing the line for the updated groupby command?

Comment: @gehbiszumeis, how would you rewrite the depth column to match the average depth per each layer?

Comment: @PEBKAC  this answer is good (better than mine ;-), but I think could be further streamlined to these 2 lines, but I'll leave the edit to you or gehbiszumeis:  (1) `df1.depth = pd.cut( df1.depth, pd.interval_range(start=1.0,end=2.5,freq=0.5) )` (2) `df1.groupby('depth').mean()`

Comment: @JohnE, that's really cool! Thank you so much, I learnt a lot from you today!!

Comment: @JohnE, one last question: how would you then update the depth column to match the average of every layer?

Comment: Thanks, happy to help!  Instead of renaming "depth" make a new variable "depth_interval" and groupby on that.  Then you should retain the depth column and it will get averaged like the other columns.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to define a grouper, then do a standard groupby.  Doubling and then using integer truncation is one way.  Note that I also subtracted a tiny amount (`sub(0.001)`) just so this would match the bin edges for @gehbiszumeis answer -- but this is just an arbitrary bin edge decision and could be left out.

```
df1['grp'] = df1.depth.sub(0.001).mul(2).astype(int)
df1.groupby('grp').mean()
```

Results:

```
    depth       350       351       352       353       354       355
grp                                                                   
2      1.3  5.986384  6.154609  6.322835  6.427094  6.517312  6.397441
3      1.8  2.266104  2.357551  2.448998  2.502890  2.548537  2.594184
4      2.1  1.573693  1.622722  1.671752  1.718081  1.763818  1.809555
```

Alternatively you can use a `pd.bin` approach like @gehbiszumeis which is a little more elegant.  Here is a variation on that approach which results in an interval index:

```
df1['depth_range'] = pd.cut( df1.depth, pd.interval_range(start=1.0,end=2.5,freq=0.5) )
df1.groupby('depth_range').mean()

             depth       350       351       352       353       354       355
depth_range                                                                   
(1.0, 1.5]     1.3  5.986384  6.154609  6.322835  6.427094  6.517312  6.397441
(1.5, 2.0]     1.8  2.266104  2.357551  2.448998  2.502890  2.548537  2.594184
(2.0, 2.5]     2.1  1.573693  1.622722  1.671752  1.718081  1.763818  1.809555
```

Comment: thank you, the problem is that I would like to "shrink" the dataframe and average all **n** rows, so in this case first average the depth layers from 1.1 to 1.6 m, get a mean output per column, then move to the next chunk of rows that form a 0.5 bin etc.

Comment: that looks cool, thank you. However, I'm not sure why you get 3 rows and such vals if we have a range between 1.1 and 2.1? Shouldn't the first layer include 1.1-1.6 interval and the second the next 5 rows and so on? So shouldn't the mean vals be 1.35 and 1.85 in this case? What's the role of `mul(2)` in this case?

Comment: @PEBKAC  no problem, and btw I added `sub(0.001)` just so it would be obvious that both answers get essentially the same results if the bin edges line up.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
In [33]: g = df1.groupby(by=lambda i: 1.35 if i < 1.7 else 1.85)

In [34]: g.mean()
Out[34]:
           350       351       352       353       354       355  depth
1.35  7.898167  8.094912  8.291657  8.421007  8.535562  8.650118   1.10
1.85  3.493796  3.608861  3.723926  3.794699  3.855750  3.811756   1.65
```

NOTE that you'll still need to update the 'depth' column. Also, the `by` function for the `groupby` could maybe be made "smarter" - figure out the depths to use automatically based on the dataframe...

Comment: yeah exactly, I'm trying to figure out how to write a condition so one can define the dz desired for binning?, something like `df1.groupby(df.index / n).mean()`